# How to access a variable from one .js file into another html file?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've been trying to access a variable that is in my back-end `.js` file and now I want to access the same variable in the HTML file.

I've tried using the export and import method but no luck, e.g.:

```
module.exports = {<variable-name};
```

and then in the HTML `<script>` tag I am trying to `import` it.

```
import{<variable-name>}`
```

I don't know that we have to include any library for that if anyone knows how to achieve this?

This is the example:
index.js file:-

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Version_2 = fs.readFileSync(
  `${__dirname}/starter/templates/Version_2.html`,
  'utf-8'
);
const table = fs.readFileSync(
  `${__dirname}/starter/templates/table.html`,
  'utf-8'
);
const data = fs.readFileSync(
  `${__dirname}/starter/dev-data/data.json`,
  'utf-8'
);
const dataObj = JSON.parse(data);
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  const { query, pathname } = url.parse(req.url, true);
let stream = 0;
   for(var i=0;i<dataObj.length;i++)
   {
    stream++;
   }
```

Version2.html:-

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4"
               style="margin-top : 65px;">
            {%TABLEEG%}
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4"
               style="margin-top : 65px;">
            {%TABLEEG1%}
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4"
               style="margin-top : 65px;">
            {%TABLEEG2%}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

So i want to access the "stream" variable from the server side JavaScript(index.js) to the client side HTML(Version2.html) so that the html page can be dynamically divided into grids based on the backend data.

Comment: You can't access back-end variables directly from the front-end. You need to use AJAX.

Comment: The question does not make any sense. How could you get a backend variable in the front end? Please read web architecture.  You need ajax for this

Comment: In the last month, I've seen this question 5 times. It's quite strange why did it became so popular. 

Comment: Or if you want to render the HTML page on server, you should take a look at templating engines

Comment: @sibabratswain okay let me ask you like this, i want to access a js file variable into my html page so cant we do it, similar to including a src in the script tag... can you just tell me about the method which i am trying to incorporate...i.e exports and import

Comment: @Barmar can you tell a bit more about the AJAX part

Comment: I'm not sure what more to say. AJAX is a general mechanism for sending messages from the client to the server. The server runs a program and sends a response back. That response can include the values of variables.

Comment: @High let me put it like this, in my js file i have a function and it is returning a value of number of records in my array data, now i want to access that number of records in my html page so that i can divide my screen grid into that number.

Comment: you have many option, using `ajax` call or `template engines` or using framework like `react`, `vue` or `angular`; `ajax` is simpler than other.

Comment: @Zoldszemesostoros because of the rise of node.js. one language for all!

Comment: can i use that as a global variable and access it in my html page?

Comment: @aakashgilotra : Why are you tagging this as _shell_? Where is the connection to POSIX shell (or any other shell) in your question?

Comment: [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)/[export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) is for [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)  and not for embedded scripts.  You'll have to add `type="module"` and modularize it.  Post actual code.  You can use https://repl.it or something similar for your server side code

Comment: @user120242 yes it is like i have my data array of objects in .json file and i have a variable x = which counts the no. of objects. This is done in my index.js file, but after this i have to make grids based on this data 'x' in my html page, and i think that if i can get the value of 'x' inside my script tag it might be possible. any suggestions?

Comment: why can't you just build the grid inside index.js?  anyways, if your script tag runs after index.js runs, it has access to all global variables index.js has created.  post an actual example so we can actually help you

Comment: @user120242 actually i have updated the question with my example, can you guide tell me something about it?